# XPath does not return the content

Tags: python, xpath

I am trying to extract 'Total Marks' from [Result](http://results.vtu.ac.in/results/result_page.php?usn=3ae13cs089) using Python 3. The web page is shown in the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dkZ93.png), from here, I'm trying to extract the data '**515**'. The XPath of the content (from Firebug) is shown as:

```
/html/body/div/div/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/b
```

The code snippet used is:

```
summary_data_xpath = '//tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/b/text()'
data = html_tree.xpath(summary_data_xpath)
print(data)
```

But I get the output: `[]`

I tried using absolute path (XPath given by Firebug). I also tried to start reference from the '`//table`', but I got the same result.

The two tables are structured as:

```html
...
<div>
    <div>
        Upper Table with subject marks
    </div>
    Lower Table with subject marks and division
</div>
...
```

How can I extract the total marks '**515**' from the table?
Thanks in advance for any assistance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the related preceding "Total Marks" label via [`following-sibling` axis](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/following-sibling):

```
import requests
from lxml.html import fromstring


url = "http://results.vtu.ac.in/results/result_page.php?usn=3ae13cs089"

response = requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.96 Safari/537.36'})

root = fromstring(response.content)
summary_data_xpath = './/td[b = "Total Marks"]/following-sibling::td/b'
data = root.xpath(summary_data_xpath)[0].text.strip(": ")
print(data)
```

Prints `515`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the instant reply. It worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

As there's no really good id usage here, I'd use the following:

```
//tr[./td/b/text()="Total Marks"]/td[2]/b
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! The XPath extracts the data.